# how can i find if a certain part of the screen is clicked?

Tags: javascript

I can find if the screen is clicked, but where it is clicked. I have tried

```
.click(margin=10?){alert("you clicked at margin 10!")}
```

but it for some reason the syntax says the margin is unset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can begin with something like below one.

the below code simply add a document wide click listener and retrieve the X and Y coordinates of the pointer click.

```js
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);
});
```